# Looking for MIPS-based computer (netbook or similar gadget) for studying JVM multithreading

Tags: processor-architecture

I am studying JVM multi-threading and I need to try it on other architectures, Arm is already abandoned so I am searching for with a netbook or other small computing device. Can anyone recommend something?

Requirements:

```
MIPS CPU
preferably dual+ core
```

Could be something like Raspberry pi, but MIPS based.

Comment: Why is ARM abandoned? The kind of device you're looking for is far more commonly ARM-based than MIPS-based. And why not an emulator?

Comment: Already have ARM it is my phone rooted running Fedora alongside Android, so I can experiment. Now searching for MIPS